# Continuous paused loop through table elements

Tags: jquery

I want to continuously cycle through the rows of a table, highlighting a row, then pausing and moving to the next row. When I reach the end I want to go back around and start at the beginning again.

I liked roXon's answer the best because it felt more concise and functional, so I expanded it to work with three tables. But now there's code duplication -- what is the most elegant way to write the code without duplication, that allows for different tables and colors? Here's the working three-table solution (also, is the inner function strictly necessary?):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.highlight1 { background:gold; }
.highlight2 { background:lightblue; }
.highlight3 { background:lightgreen; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $TR1=$('#table1 tr:gt(0)'), TRn1=$TR1.length, c1=0;
    var $TR2=$('#table2 tr:gt(0)'), TRn2=$TR2.length, c2=0;
    var $TR3=$('#table3 tr:gt(0)'), TRn3=$TR3.length, c3=0;
    function loop(){
      $TR1.eq(c1++%TRn1).addClass('highlight1').siblings().removeClass('highlight1');
      $TR2.eq(c2++%TRn2).addClass('highlight2').siblings().removeClass('highlight2');
      $TR3.eq(c3++%TRn3).addClass('highlight3').siblings().removeClass('highlight3');
    }
    setInterval(loop, 1000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1" border="1">
  <th>Table One</th>
  <tr><td>Table Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 6</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="table2" border="1">
  <th>Table Two</th>
  <tr><td>Table Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 6</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="table3" border="1">
  <th>Table Three</th>
  <tr><td>Table Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table Row 6</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CSS class `.highlight`
Be more specific while using selectors. I added a table ID

```
var $TR = $('#highlight_table tr:gt(0)'),
    TRn = $TR.length,
      c = 0 ;

function loop(){
   $TR.eq( c++ % TRn ).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
}

setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ecukub/1/edit)**

`c++%TRn` will increment our counter on each loop iteration, but thanks to the `Modulo` operator - once the counter and the number of TR elements matches - our counter will be reset to `0` (e.g. `4%4=0`)

Comment: Making it hard to read, it is not gonna make it any easier for a newcomer

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the comment, I think a kid could understand my explanation and perhaps learn something new. And there was really no need to edit my answer but thanks any way.

Comment: @roXon: Inlining a ton of variable declarations and making a one-liner isn't really the most readable way of doing it.

Comment: I edited the original question to incorporate this answer; see above question about best way to eliminate code duplication. Thanks!

Comment: @user1677663 take a look at HTML, CSS and JQ http://jsbin.com/ilovac/1/edit (you're welcome! thx)

Comment: @user1677663 the "inner function you mentioned is a shorthand for `document ready`. So it's not needed, pick the one you most like.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setInterval()` for this:

```
var $rows = $('table tr td');
var index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    $rows.eq(index).addClass('highlighted');

    index = (index + 1) % $rows.length;
}, 100);​
```

If you're only planning on having one active element at a time, use an `id` instead of a `class`.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JCSL3/3/**

Comment: You're awesome. Stackoverflow is awesome. JQuery is awesome.

Comment: @user1677663: You forgot that you're awesome.

Comment: by **not** advising the OP to be more specific on using it's selectors it's not a really good way of "doing it", than `++` operator is elementary, joining variables with a comma would not scare anyone, explaining the `modulo` operator ... ok, I've done that part ;) Happy New Year Blender

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery delay() method is for animation.  Try using a setInterval timer instead.

```
var rows =  $('tr:gt(0)'),
   rowIndex = 0,
   interval;

interval = setInterval(function() {
    rows.removeClass('highlight');
    $(rows[rowIndex]).addClass('highlight');
    rowIndex++;
    if (rowIndex > rows.length) {
        rowIndex = 0;            
    }
},1500);
```

Comment: Instead of using `$(rows[rowIndex])`, just do `rows.eq(rowIndex)`